# Unity 3d doesnt not contain a definition

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercontroler : MonoBehaviour {

    public static playercontroler sharedinstance;

    void Awake(){
        sharedinstance = this;
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }
    public void KillPlayer(){
        GameManager.sharedistance.GameOver ();
        animator.SetBool ("isAlive", false);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class killtriger : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D theObject){
        if (theObject.tag == "Player") {
            playercontroler.sharedinstance.KillPlayer ();
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is that unity return:

"playercontroler" doesnt not contain a definition for sharedinstance

what is the problem? thanks

Comment: You should use the Class name ie `PlayerControler` instead of `playerControler` in your script since it's a singleton

Comment: I think you need to initialize static variables if I recall it right. Try public static playercontroler sharedinstance = null;

Comment: @armnotstrong No, it should be `PlayerControler` because it's *a class name*: `public class playercontroler` -> `public class PlayerControler`.

Comment: @Draco18s hmm，didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that will fix everything, but you should check if playercontroler.sharedinstance have been set before using it.

```
public class killtriger : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D theObject){
        if (theObject.tag == "Player" && playercontroler.sharedinstance) {
            playercontroler.sharedinstance.KillPlayer ();
        }
    }

}
```

Also make sure the variable name is right. You have the variables sharedistance and sharedinstance in your code. They are for different objects, but I imagine they should have the same name.